# Recursively calling a method ignores checks and skips breakpoints

Tags: c#, sockets, streamreader

I am currently developing a chat server as a school project.
I have some conditions for names on the server, so i created a method to call that should enforce those rules.
Anytime a name is not acceptable. The method will call it self again.
Among other things, the method is supposed to prevent people from having the same name.

I start the server, telnet into it for client1. I then set the name of client1 to: bob

I then telnet into the server for client2. If i try to set the name to bob, it is rejected - as it should be.
If i then set the name to bobby, it is accepted. The method completes and the name is set.

Now comes the weird part. After setting the name to an available valid name, the name changes again. To the first (unavailable) name that i tried (bob).

So i tried with some breakpoints, thinking that i made a mistake in the recursive call to the method. But on the passthrough where the name is changed to bob, it does not activate the breakpoints i put on the reader, or the check that should prevent the name to be set to an unavailable name.

My code:

```
class NameHandler
{
    private readonly List<string> AllNames = new List<string>();

    public void SetName(StreamWriter writer, Client client)
    {
        var reader = new StreamReader(new NetworkStream(client.GetSocket));
        var name = reader.ReadLine();

        if(!IsNameAvailable(name))
        {
            writer.WriteLine("That name is in use. Pick an other one");
            SetName(writer, client);
        }

        try
        {
            client.Name = name;
        }
        catch(ArgumentOutOfRangeException)
        {
            writer.WriteLine("Max length of name is 10.");
            writer.WriteLine("Try again please:");
            SetName(writer, client);
        }
        catch(ArgumentNullException)
        {
            writer.WriteLine("Invalid name");
            writer.WriteLine("Try again please:");
            SetName(writer, client);
        }
        catch (ArgumentException)
        {
            writer.WriteLine("The name may not contain spaces");
            writer.WriteLine("Try again please:");
            SetName(writer, client);
        }
        AllNames.Add(client.Name.ToLower());
        writer.WriteLine("Your name was successfully updated.");
    }

    private bool IsNameAvailable(string name)
    {
        return !AllNames.Contains(name.ToLower());
    }
}
```

The Client class, contains a unique socket passed to it on instantiation.
Each Client has their own unique local port. This has been verified multiple times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that after `SetName` has completed successfully with `bobby`, it returns to where it was called from, ie here:

```
if(!IsNameAvailable(name))
{
    writer.WriteLine("That name is in use. Pick an other one");
    SetName(writer, client); //Control returns to here
}
```

The local `name` variable is still set to `bob`, and the next block of code then executes:

```
try
{
    client.Name = name;
}
```

Setting the `Name` property to the one you've already found to be unavailable.  The simple fix is to return out of the function as soon as you've recursively called `SetName` again:

```
if(!IsNameAvailable(name))
{
    writer.WriteLine("That name is in use. Pick an other one");
    SetName(writer, client);
    return;
}
```

This way when control returns to the outer function, it will return straight away and not attempt to change the name any further.  You probably need to return immediately after each of the calls within the exception handlers too.

Comment: Thank you! This is actually really obvious once it was pointed out. It worked, and i am now on to implementing a whisper function :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing an else part. The assignment `client.Name = name;` is always performed, even if the name is "not available", after the recursively called function returns. I assume that is not intentional.

Comment: Thank you. i cannot see who answered first (both says 1 hour ago). But i will award the answer to James, since his was more detailed.

Comment: @MortenToudahl Just FYI - if you hover over the part where it says "answered x hours ago", the tooltip displays the exact timestamp.